# How to specify an interface with conditional properties in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a helper function to create new HTML elements

```
interface NewElement {
  type: string;
  className: string;
  innerText: string;
  href: string;
}
const createElement = ({ type, className, innerText, href }: NewElement) => {
  const element = document.createElement(type);
  innerText ? (element.innerText = innerText) : null;
  href ? (element.href = href) : null;
  className ? (element.className = className) : null;
  return element;
};
```

If I want to create a `<li>` tag I don't need to pass the `href` for example

```
const li = createElement({ type: "li", className: "category" });
```

The warning, rightly states `...Type '{ type: string; className: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'NewElement': innerText, href`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: this is usually done in object oriented programming with a base class that contains all common properties and classes that extend the base class with their own properties. Worth noting that typescript already has types for HTMLElements

Comment: @bryan60 how would that look like?

Comment: try studying the typescript dom library https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript, you can specify a field as optional as below:

```
interface NewElement {
  type: string;
  className: string;
  innerText?: string;
  href?: string;
}
```

It's also a good practice to give those optional fields a default value in your function. For example:

```
const createElement = ({ type, className, innerText = "", href = "" }: NewElement) => {
  // function body
};
```

Then, you can use the function as in your example:

```
const li = createElement({ type: "li", className: "category" });
```

Comment: Are those properties *nullable* or *optional*?

Comment: My mistake. In my example, it means _optional_.

Comment: Great! I still get an error 4th line of the function `href ? (element.href = href) : null;` it says "Property 'href' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'", how would you fix it

Comment: The href attribute is only available on the anchor tag, not on all tags. So if you use it, for example, on li, it will throw an error since there is no href attr in li tag